# How to fix "Method in class cannot be applied to given types" error?

Tags: java, methods, getter

```
class WageCalculator_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       WagecalculatorApp WageCalculatorObject = new WagecalculatorApp(); 
    }

    private double baseRate;
    private double overtimeMultiplier;
    private int hours;
    private int overtime;
    private int overtimeHours;
    private int wages;
    private String multi;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public WageCalculator_1(double baseRate, int hours) 
    {
       this(baseRate, 1.5, hours);
    }

    public WageCalculator_1(double baseRate, double overtimeMultiplier, int hours) {
       System.out.print("Enter your base rate: ");
       baseRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

       WageCalculatorObject.wagecalc(baseRate);
       System.out.print("Enter your hours: ");
       hours = keyboard.nextInt();

       WageCalculatorObject.wagecalc(hours);
       System.out.print("Would you like to enter an overtime multiplier (yes/no)? ");
       multi = keyboard.next();

       if (hours > 40) {  
           System.out.print("what is the overtime multiplier? ");
           overtimeMultiplier = keyboard.nextInt();
       } else if (hours <= 40) { 
           wages = (int) (hours * baseRate);
           overtimeMultiplier = 0;    
       } else {   
           wages = (int) (40 * baseRate);       
           overtimeHours = hours - 40;
           overtime = (int) (overtimeHours * ( 1.5 * baseRate));   
           wages += overtime;              
       }   
    }
}
```

I have been having issues with WageCalculatorObject. keeps giving me that error when I try to use it. I have been struggling with this quite a bit and don't know what else to do with it. It gives me [no error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv21s.jpg).

Comment: Please fix your formatting and explain more clearly what you're having a problem with please. What does "I have been having issues" actually mean?

Comment: at the bottom I say im having issues with WageCalculatorObject it gives me that error and I have been trying to fix it for hours but I just don't know what im doing wrong. I am trying to use this in another class and thats what im having the problem with.

Comment: OK, so what super-human powers should I use to determine what the error is?

Comment: um.. what? you ok?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40142854/edit) your post to include the actual error you're getting and while you're at it make your code look as though you'd be proud of it.

Comment: I dont know how to do any of that. i've never used this site before. I had a question because I couldn't figure it out. I explained the exact error im getting in the title, I didn't think it would be such a big deal.

Comment: What is the code for WageCalculatorObject ? WagecalculatorApp? There's multiple classes at work here and it's really confusing what you're trying to do. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: That error could be given for any one of these methods which you've not provided. Your code is incomplete and formatted in a way that makes helping you more difficult than need be. I added a link in my previous comment that takes you to the edit page. Copy/paste your code in the editor, select all of it, and click the `{}` button at the top. *Please* I would also suggest to not put information regarding the problems and such in comments in the code but rather as text in the post.

Comment: it now says "cannot find symbol" I try to run it but it just comes up blank. I would love to post it but it really is just blank. I don't know whats wrong with it thats why I came here.               I added a picture of what it says.

Comment: Cannot find what symbol? It's in the error message. You're not helping anyone here, least of all yourself.

Comment: ill post another picture of what happens when i run it

Comment: @Koryba If you've never used this site before, then be prepared to have every one of your questions get spammed with downvotes, just because you didn't provide enough information. You'll soon learn that it's impossible for others to give constructive feedback without downvoting.

Comment: Where is `WageCalculatorObject` defined? Your code doesn't show it, and there's clearly an error there - did you define this class?

Comment: i dont know. im new to java and had a question thats what im asking you all.

Answer (score 1):

You have no WageCalculatorApp Object. Specifically speaking, unless you give more code, while you initialize the WageCalculatorObject object, you never call it, and therefore any methods you call do not return anything as nothing exists (Unless of course you did not show your code for the WageCalculatorApp). Unless you create a WageCalculatorApp object, nothing can be returned from it as it does not exist.